# Running a bash script stored on a windows share from linux

Tags: linux, bash, network-shares

I want to run a script directly from a windows share. The windows machine is running Windows 7 and I try to run the script from Ubuntu 13.10, on the same LAN.
I tried with a bash script as well as a python script and when I run it, I have the following error:

```
zsh: permission denied: ./bc.sh
```

The share containg the script is mounted like this:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=user,passwordpass=,exec,rw,users,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 //192.168.0.3/folder /mnt/Win7
```

The script has the following rights:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 0 root root       24 Dec 10 20:50 bc.sh
```

And contains only a simple command:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Test"
```

I tried to run it with sudo but didn't work as well.

```
sudo: unable to execute ./bc.sh: Permission denied
```

I also tried with bash instead of zsh, without success.

Any idea about what I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to execute the script as

```
       sh path/to/bc.sh
```

Comment: No, that's not necessary: the script has been made executable, thus it can be run like in the OP

Comment: If this really *is* the answer (as marked) then it would be great to understand *why*. As @MariusMatutiae said, you wouldn't normally need to run it with `sh` but there's something about the network share that changes this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are three possible causes why a script might not run when invoked directly.

1. The e**x**ecute bit hasn't been set.

   ```
   [liveuser@localhost-live ~]$ ls -l ~/*.sh
   -rw-rw-rw-. 1 liveuser liveuser 28 Mar 25 07:55 /home/liveuser/testnox.sh
   -rwxrwxrwx. 1 liveuser liveuser 28 Mar 25 07:23 /home/liveuser/test.sh
   [liveuser@localhost-live ~]$ ~/test.sh
   Hello world.
   [liveuser@localhost-live ~]$ ~/testnox.sh
   bash: /home/liveuser/testnox.sh: Permission denied
   [liveuser@localhost-live ~]$ sh ~/testnox.sh
   Hello world.
   ```

   Note that you can still run it by invoking `sh` directly, as long as you've got read access. Also, check if the x bit applies to you. If the file is owned by root and it shows up as `-rwx------.` then you have to use `sudo` to run it.
2. A SELinux rule applies that prevents you from executing the file. I don't know too much about this, but using `sudo setenforce 0` beforehand can help in this case. Don't forget to use `sudo setenforce 1` when you're done.

   ```
   [liveuser@localhost-live ~]$ sestatus
   SELinux status:                 enabled
   SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
   SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
   Loaded policy name:             targeted
   Current mode:                   enforcing
   Mode from config file:          enforcing
   Policy MLS status:              enabled
   Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
   Max kernel policy version:      30
   [liveuser@localhost-live ~]$ sudo setenforce 0
   [liveuser@localhost-live ~]$ sestatus
   SELinux status:                 enabled
   SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
   SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
   Loaded policy name:             targeted
   Current mode:                   permissive
   Mode from config file:          enforcing
   Policy MLS status:              enabled
   Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
   Max kernel policy version:      30
   [liveuser@localhost-live ~]$ sudo setenforce 1
   [liveuser@localhost-live ~]$ sestatus
   SELinux status:                 enabled
   SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
   SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
   Loaded policy name:             targeted
   Current mode:                   enforcing
   Mode from config file:          enforcing
   Policy MLS status:              enabled
   Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
   Max kernel policy version:      30
   ```
3. The tree the script resides in was mounted using `noexec`, which is the default in many cases. Take care that what matters is the `(no)exec` status of the **mount**, and that `mount --bind` sometimes copies neither the status of the parent of the mount point, nor the status of the original volume.

   ```
   [liveuser@localhost-live ~]$ ls -l original
   total 4
   -rwxrwxr-x. 1 liveuser liveuser 28 Mar 25 08:14 test.sh
   [liveuser@localhost-live ~]$ ls -l alias
   total 4
   -rwxrwxr-x. 1 liveuser liveuser 28 Mar 25 08:14 test.sh
   [liveuser@localhost-live ~]$ original/test.sh
   Hello world.
   [liveuser@localhost-live ~]$ alias/test.sh
   bash: alias/test.sh: Permission denied
   [liveuser@localhost-live ~]$ sh alias/test.sh
   Hello world.
   [liveuser@localhost-live ~]$ sudo mount -o remount,exec --bind original alias
   [liveuser@localhost-live ~]$ alias/test.sh
   Hello world.
   ```

One of the reasons Linux can be frustrating is because the error messages don't really give you the detail you need to find a solution. Just `Permission denied` isn't enough to go on in my opinion. It should say what the actual cause was, for example: `Permission denied: /home/liveuser/alias was mounted with noexec`. Then you'd know how to go about fixing the problem.

Well, in any case I hope this helps.